# Morph field doesn't have a default value when seeding factory relationship

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-8

I have a `Recipe` and `Review` model:

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function reviews(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Review::class, 'reviewable');
    }
}

class Review extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

Each has a factory:

```
class RecipeFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Recipe::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->sentence(5, true),
        ];
    }
}

class ReviewFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Review::class;

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'review' => $this->faker->paragraphs(1, true),
        ];
    }
}
```

When I try to seed new test records using this:

```
Recipe::factory()->hasAttached(
    Review::factory()
        ->count(5)
);
```

I get the SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'reviewable_type' doesn't have a default value
```

How do I get Laravel to fill in the correct morph `reviewable_type` and `reviewable_id` values when seeding the related records?

Comment: Wouldn't the relationship between a recipe and review be a one-to-many? A review belongs to a single recipe and a recipe has many reviews, right? Your Recipe model would `MorphMany` reviews instead of `MorphToMany` and your Review model would define a `MorphTo` reviewable relationship.

Comment: You're right, I had that backward. However, changing to `MorphMany` doesn't fix the factory error.

Comment: I assume you reverted back from using `hasAttached` to `Recipe::factory()->has(Review::factory()->count(5))->create()`?

Comment: That resolved it!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have a program, and a form, the form can be attached to various tables.

When I created my seeder I would grab a program, create a form, and then got the error `General error: 1364 Field 'formable_type' doesn't have a default value`

I fixed this by updating my migration to use `nullableMorphs`.

`$table->nullableMorphs('formable');`

Hope that will help someone.